# Most efficient way to animate resizing of NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to scale/resize an NSImageView to 120% of it's original size in a 0.1 second animation block, and then return to it's original size after the animation block is complete. What's the quickest and least cpu intensive way of doing this?

I'm basically looking for a code equivalent to the following code that's used in iOS, but I need it for a Mac app:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.1];
image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(image.transform, newSize, newSize);
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.1];
image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(image.transform,  originalSize, originalSize);
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: the animation proxy provided for every AppKit object?

Answer (score 3):

It might take up a bit of CPU depending on whether the image is being scaled inside of the `NSImageView`, but you can accomplish the same thing using `NSAnimationContext` like this:

```
NSRect oldFrame = self.imageView.frame;
NSRect newFrame = NSMakeRect(self.imageView.frame.origin.x,
                             self.imageView.frame.origin.y,
                             self.imageView.frame.size.width*1.2f,
                             self.imageView.frame.size.height*1.2f);

[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context){
    // Animating to the new frame...
    [context setDuration:0.1f];
    [[self.imageView animator] setFrame:newFrame];
} completionHandler:^{
    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context){
        // Back to the old frame...
        [context setDuration:0.1f];
        [[self.imageView animator] setFrame:oldFrame];
    } completionHandler:nil];
}];
```

But that way of doing it works on OS X 10.7 and up.

This can also be done in a way that looks a bit like the `UIView` code, and works with 10.5 and up:

```
- (void)whatever {
    NSRect oldFrame = self.imageView.frame;
    NSRect newFrame = NSMakeRect(self.imageView.frame.origin.x,
                                 self.imageView.frame.origin.y,
                                 self.imageView.frame.size.width*1.2f,
                                 self.imageView.frame.size.height*1.2f);

    [self performSelector:@selector(animateImageViewToFrame:)
               withObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:newFrame]
               afterDelay:0];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animateImageViewToFrame:)
               withObject:[NSValue valueWithRect:oldFrame]
               afterDelay:0.1f];
}



- (void)animateImageViewToFrame:(NSValue*)frameValue {
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.1f];
    // Get smaller
    [[self.imageView animator] setFrame:[frameValue rectValue]];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
}
```

Of course, it would be brilliant if this worked:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.1f];
[[self.imageView animator] setFrame:newFrame];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.1f];
[[self.imageView animator] setFrame:oldFrame];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Or even better:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.1f];
[[self.imageView animator] setFrame:newFrame];
[[self.imageView animator] setFrame:oldFrame];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

But neither of those do anything, for reasons that I cannot figure out.

See the [NSAnimationContext Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSAnimationContext_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more information.

Comment: As far as I know NSAnimationContext can use a lot of CPU power, are there some other possibilites?